# Change table from InnoDB to ARCHIVE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb, archive

I try change my table from InnoDB to ARCHIVE with SQL command:

```
ALTER TABLE data_obook ENGINE = ARCHIVE;
```

But it always show me only error:

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'coincity.#sql-1350_8a' (errno: -1)
```

My structure:

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data_obook` (
  `market_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `curr_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `book_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `price` float NOT NULL,
  `amount` double NOT NULL,
  `stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`market_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Can somebody help me with solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the [ARCHIVE Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/archive-storage-engine.html) does not support indexes of any kind, your main problem is the presence of the  `PRIMARY KEY`. Simply drop the `PRIMARY KEY`. Then, convert the Storage Engine.

There are two approaches to this

## APPROACH #1

```
ALTER TABLE date_obook DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE date_obook ENGINE=ARCHIVE;
```

## APPROACH #2

```
CREATE TABLE date_obook_new LIKE date_obook;
ALTER TABLE date_obook_new DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE date_obook_new ENGINE=ARCHIVE;
INSERT INTO date_obook_new SELECT * FROM date_obook;
ALTER TABLE date_obook RENAME date_obook_old;
ALTER TABLE date_obook_new RENAME date_obook;
DROP TABLE date_obook_old;
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

## SPECIAL NOTE

If anyone has a `PRIMARY KEY` with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute, you must remove the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute first. Then, remove the `PRIMARY KEY`, Then, convert the Storage Engine. For example, if `market_id` was defined as `int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`, do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE date_obook MODIFY market_id INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE date_obook DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE date_obook ENGINE=ARCHIVE;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ARCHIVE` engine can have an auto-increment column and for this it requires an index.

As per the docs ([5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/archive-storage-engine.html), [5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/archive-storage-engine.html), [5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/archive-storage-engine.html)):

> The ARCHIVE engine supports the AUTO_INCREMENT column attribute. The
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column can have either a unique or nonunique index.
>   Attempting to create an index on any other column results in an error.
>   The ARCHIVE engine also supports the AUTO_INCREMENT table option in
>   CREATE TABLE statements to specify the initial sequence value for a
>   new table or reset the sequence value for an existing table,
>   respectively.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table AUTO_INCREMENT=0, ENGINE=ARCHIVE;
```

It will fail with `ERROR 1022 (23000): Can't write; duplicate key in table` if you do not reset the `AUTO_INCREMENT`

If you try to do this when your `PRIMARY KEY` is not auto-increment then you will see:

```
mysql [localhost] {root} (test) > create table foo (id int primary key);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

mysql [localhost] {root} (test) > alter table foo engine=archive;
ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error -1 from storage engine
```